# Is it possible to remove URL option from vue-dropzone2?

Tags: vue.js, dropzone

I would like to remove `url` option from the vue-dropzone, because I have my own logic in `afterComplete` function, that transfers the file and then makes an action to different API - meaning - As I'm loading the files manually, I don't need the post request here at all. However, after removing that option, the error occurs:

```
Error: No URL provided.
```

Dropzone:

```
<vue-dropzone
  id="image-upload"
  ref="imgDropZone"
  :use-custom-slot="true"
  :options="dropzoneOptions"
  @vdropzone-thumbnail="filesAdded"
  @vdropzone-complete="afterComplete"
>
  <BaseButton>
    Add images
  </BaseButton>
</vue-dropzone>
```

Dropzone options:

```
dropzoneOptions: {
  thumbnailWidth: 150,
  thumbnailHeight: 150,
  addRemoveLinks: false,
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  // should stay?
  url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
  acceptedFiles: ".jpg, .jpeg, .png"
}
```

Comment: A work around would be to point it to localhost?

Comment: @MaartenDev Then I get CORS issue. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @MaartenDev however, the queue passes as expected - only unhandled error in the console is given. I will stick with it for now, but would be nice if we find better solution

Comment: Which dropzone package are you using?

Comment: @MaartenDev vue2 dropzone - `"vue2-dropzone": "^3.6.0",`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up creating my own endpoint that returns mocked down response, only to satisfy dropzone:

```
files: {
  file: ""
}
```

Maybe this is not the final, complete solution, but something you can do to get this working properly.